# After the Brexit, can we store UK data in EU region?

Tags: gdpr, brexit

Can you please tell me, whether we can store PII data belong to UK in EU region? I know the other way round is illegal. But I could not find a place where this problem address properly. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: It Depends... Get a lawyer.

Answer (score 5):

When personal data is transferred between the EU and UK, this is an “international transfer” (also called “restricted transfer” in ICO guidance).

Transfers of personal data from the UK to the EU/EEA are easy since the UK has granted an adequacy decision to the EU (see Art 45 GDPR). Nevertheless, this must be disclosed to data subjects per Art 13(1)(f) GDPR.

Transfers of personal data from the EU to the UK are different. An adequacy decision is still under negotiation, but is not guaranteed. As an interim measure, the Brexit trade deal says that transfers of personal data into the UK are *temporarily* not considered international transfers, so that no legal basis such as an adequacy decision is needed. This interim measure will expire after April, but will likely be extended to expire after June. If this temporary measures expires before an adequacy decision is in place, alternative transfer mechanisms such as *standard contractual clauses* (SCCs) have to be used. In a way, the temporary measure allows an extended transition period for putting SCCs into place.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. but can you please elaborate little on how can we store data?

Comment: @yello_flash What particular concern do you have about storage? If you want to store data in some country, you must transfer it there first.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. initially, I actually did not consider the fact you mentioned above. When I refer to the data transfer, I meant access to the UK data after storing data in the EU region data center. 
Let's say you have a PHP application coupled with MySQL database which contains UK PII data, I want to know whether this database can be stored in EU region data center? what is the legal aspect of it?

Comment: @yello_flash I'm having a bit of trouble following what exactly you're saying. Some of your processing activities may fall under the UK GDPR, such as any processing of personal data relating to the offering of goods and services to people in the UK. Processing activities can include transfers to and from the EU. But since the UK has granted an adequacy decision to the EU, transfers from the UK to the EU are generally fine. Subsequent transfers out of the EU might be a bit more tricky, but are by no means impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: could you please tell me if we are to transfer EU data into the UK, do we have any other alternatives other than SCCs? if not can you share a template of an SCC which we can use to prepare our own SCC? I just tried to find a processor to controller template, but could now find one. can you please help me with this?

Comment: @yello_flash The EU has created a *draft* adequacy decision, and will likely pass it in time. Then, no SCCs will be required. If you want to set up SCCs in case the adequacy procedure fails, you will have to use the terms that have been pre-approved. For EU → UK transfers between controllers, I think you'll have to adapt the terms approved for the Data Protection Directive that preceded the GDPR (see: https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/law-topic/data-protection/international-dimension-data-protection/standard-contractual-clauses-scc_en)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Hi @amon do you now any place where we can get alerted on updates with regards to this brexit? any forum? a reliable place?

Comment: Hi @amon,
Do you have any latest updates on the UK-EU adequacy decision?  The grace period also slowly reaching the last few days. I checked several news posts, but each had mentioned still the adequacy decision has not been concluded yet.

Comment: @yello_flash Yes, adequacy has not been granted yet, but it's likely that the EC will do so in time. The draft decision has received mixed responses from stakeholders such as the EU parliament and the EDPB, in particular due to the UK's immigration exception for GDPR rights, and due to the Investigatory Powers act (which was recently ruled to be a violation of ECHR). But that's unlikely to be a blocker, especially since the adequacy will expire after a couple of years.

Comment: @yello_flash FYI the European Commission has today granted the adequacy decision. The [adequacy overview page](https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/law-topic/data-protection/international-dimension-data-protection/adequacy-decisions_en) has been updated, the full decision is [here (PDF)](https://ec.europa.eu/info/sites/default/files/decision_on_the_adequate_protection_of_personal_data_by_the_united_kingdom_-_general_data_protection_regulation_en.pdf).

Comment: Hi @amon, Thanks for informing me. This was really helpful